# t-sql select max value between two columns, or col one when col two is null

Tags: t-sql

This is not easy for me to describe in the title (please forgive me), but here is my problem:

Suppose you have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Subscriptions (product char(3), start_date datetime, end_date datetime);

INSERT INTO @Subscriptions 
VALUES('ABC', '2015-01-28 00:00:00', '2016-02-15 00:00:00'),
    ('ABC', '2016-02-04 12:08:00', NULL),
    ('DEF', '2013-04-15 00:00:00', '2013-06-10 00:00:00'),
    ('GHI', '2013-01-11 00:00:00', '2013-04-08 00:00:00');
```

Now I want to find out for how long a subscription has been either active or passive. I thus need to select the newest end_dates grouped by product, BUT if end_date is null, then I want start_date.

So - I have:

```
product start_date          end_date
ABC     28-01-2015 00:00    15-02-2016 00:00
ABC     04-02-2016 12:08    NULL
DEF     15-04-2013 00:00    10-06-2013 00:00
GHI     11-01-2013 00:00    08-04-2013 00:00
```

What I want to find in my query:

```
product relevant_date
ABC 04-02-2016 12:08
DEF 10-06-2013 00:00
GHI 08-04-2013 00:00
```

I have tried using a union, and that seems to work, but it is very slow, and my question is: is there a more efficient way to solve this (I am using MS SQL Server 2012):

```
SELECT [product] 
    ,MAX([start_date]) AS start_date
    ,NULL AS [end_date]
    ,MAX([start_date]) AS relevant_date
FROM Subscriptions  
where end_date IS NULL
GROUP BY product

UNION 

SELECT [product] 
    ,NULL
    ,MAX([end_date])
    ,MAX([end_date])
FROM Subscriptions  
where end_date IS not NULL and product not in (SELECT product FROM Subscriptions  
where end_date IS NULL)
GROUP BY product
```

(If you have a suggestion for another title for my question, I am also all ears!)

Comment: How can the product `ABC` have a `start_date` in the second row earlier than the `end_date` in the first row?

Comment: you mean earlier @iamdave :-)

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze Ha, right you are!

Comment: Not clear to me.   Need more explanation and nor sample data.

Comment: iamdave - that is exactly what is causing the problem here. We actually had a subscriber who signed op for a new subscription to the same product, before the old one had run out. It can happen :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For version 2012 or higher you can use a combination of `distinct`, `first_value` and `isnull`, like this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        product, 
        FIRST_VALUE(ISNULL(end_date,start_date)) 
            OVER(PARTITION BY product 
                 ORDER BY ISNULL(end_date, '9999-12-31') DESC) AS EndDate
FROM Subscriptions
```

Results:

```
product EndDate
ABC     04.02.2016 12:08:00
DEF     10.06.2013 00:00:00
GHI     08.04.2013 00:00:00
```

For versions between 2008 and 2012, you can use a `cte` with `row_number` to get the same effect:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  product,
            ISNULL(end_date,start_date) As relevant_date,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY product ORDER BY ISNULL(end_date, '9999-12-31') DESC) As rn
    FROM Subscriptions
)

SELECT  product, 
        relevant_date
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/FHQ69439)

Comment: All of your suggestions seems to get the job done, and I appreciate your answers and comments. The tricky part was exactly that for product 'ABC', a new subscription had started before the old one had run out, so simply finding the latest date was not enough. The reason I chose this answer is that the cte-solution seems to run a bit faster than the other solutions, and that was what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

If the second ABC row is showing the incorrect `start_date` then this query should work

```
SELECT S.product
     , relevant_date = MAX(ISNULL(S.end_date,S.start_date))
FROM dbo.Subscriptions S
GROUP BY S.product
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
    select s1.product,MAX(case when useStartDate=1 then s1.startDate else s1.endDate end) 'SubscriptionDate'
    from @Subscriptions s1
    join (select s2s1.product, max(case when s2s1.endDate is null then 1 else 0 end) 'useStartDate' from @Subscriptions s2s1 group by s2s1.product) s2 on s1.product=s2.product
    group by s1.product
```